# What is the relationship between pre-image of a function and its inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

What are the relationships and differences between the pre-image of a function and its inverse.

For example, the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{2x}{x+1}
\end{equation}
is not surjective, so it is not invertible. Can I talk about the pre-image of say zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, whenever $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a map, for all $A\subseteq Y$, the preimage of $A$ is defined to be:
$$f^{-1}(A)=\{x\in X\textrm{ s.t. }f(x)\in A\}.$$
Notice that for $A$ such that $A\cap f(X)=\varnothing$, then $f^{-1}(A)=\varnothing$.

If  $f$ is invertible, then the direct image by $f^{-1}$ is the preimage by $f$.

In your case, you have to solve for $x$, the following equation:
$$\frac{2x}{x+1}=0.$$

*Remark.* Your map is not defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.